# SQLite query - Limit occurrence of value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a query that return this result. How can i limit the occurrence of a value from the 4th column.

```
19  1   _BOURC01    1   
20  1   _BOURC01    3   2019-11-18
20  1   _BOURC01    3   2017-01-02
21  1   _BOURC01    6   
22  1   _BOURC01    10  
23  1   _BOURC01    13  2016-06-06
24  1   _BOURC01    21  2016-09-19
```

My Query:

```
SELECT "sk"."id" AS "id", "sk"."active" AS "active", "sk"."id_speaker" AS "id_speaker", "sk"."Speech" AS "Speech", "34 Program Weekend"."date" AS "date"
FROM "we"
LEFT JOIN "we" we" ON "we"."Speech" = "34 Program Weekend"."theme_id"
WHERE "id_speaker" = "_BOURC01"
ORDER BY id_speaker, Speech, date DESC
```

Thanks

Comment: What output do you actually want here?

Comment: I want to remove `20  1   _BOURC01    3   2017-01-02` from the result

Comment: Based on what logic?

Comment: In the 4th column ,wich is the speech column from the request, i want only one occurence of every value listed.

Comment: Why do you mention only the 4th column? All 4 columns are the same in rows 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.id, s.active, s.id_speaker, s.Speech
                                 ORDER BY p.date DESC) rn
    FROM "_44_SpeakerSpeech" s
    LEFT JOIN "_34_programWeekend" p ON s.Speech = p.theme_id
    WHERE s.id_speaker = '_BOURC01'
)

SELECT id, active, id_speaker, Speech, date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This logic assumes that when two or more records all have the same columns values (excluding the date), you want to retain only the latest record.